# How to add existing file to project without the file being copied? VS2022 CSPROJ

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2022, csproj

I want this file structure:

```
  /project/file1.cs
  /project/file2.cs
  /otherpath/commonstuff/fileA.cs
  /otherpath/commonstuff/fileB.cs
```

And I want these four files compiled as part of the project. I don't want `fileA.cs` or `fileB.cs` copied into the `project` folder. How do I do this?

I don't want to put `fileA.cs` into a library. I need all four files to be in the same assembly named `project` when I finish. `Project` is a DLL project for a game mod.

Comment: You can add it as a link.

Comment: How can I add it as a link? If I knew what a link was, I probably wouldn't have posted a question. EDIT: Found it. Could have mention it was right there on the Add Existing Item dialog.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add this as a link. To add, let's say `Linked.cs`, add the below into csproj file:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <Compile Include="..\..\..\..\%PATH%\Linked.cs" Link="Linked.cs" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Comment: I wish the "Add as Link" drop down on the Add Existing Item Dialog was more prominent. Thanks.